# Adding href in Wall of jomsocial like Facebook

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook, joomla

> In Facebook Wall, if you add a href link or URL of the website, Facebook will grab the images and description of that particular link and show it on the post.

How to implement this in Jomsocial?

At least tell how to implement using the normal PHP and Javascript or Jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this laying around. Create a div with id="showthumb", create a textarea.. to be used as the obj in this function.

```
function getthumb ($obj)
{    
     $obj.keydown (function (e) //obj is the textbox
     {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.charCode == 32) { //user pressed space.
        var t_content = $obj.val ();
        var t_urls = t_content.match (/https?:\/\/([-\w\.]+)+(:\d+)?(\/([\w/_\.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?/);

        if (t_urls != null) {
            if (t_urls.length > 0) {
                $('#showthumb').html ('<img src='+t_urls['input']+'>');
            }
        }
    }
 });
}
```

you can probably set it inside an editable div.btw.. I learned this from [here](http://youhack.me/2011/06/25/create-a-facebook-wall-system-using-php-and-jquery-part-1/)

Comment: oh very good information . @xlordt. Thank you

Comment: np, although I would pass that to a php script for a more in-depth check.

Answer (score 1):

A Simple approach would be like this:
Suppose you have a textarea where user type in their link.

Step1: Use `onchange`  event of `textarea` to  know if somebody typed in something.

Step2: Use Jquery to make sure if it is Url . Code will be something like this.

some regex to extract the correct url from textarea like this

```
 var regex=/Your Regex to know url/ 
 var url= regex.mathc($('#textareaid').val()).
```

Step3: Now you got the url . Send it to server using.

```
 $.ajax({
                       url:submit.php
                       type:'POST'
                       success:// do your dom mainpulation code here by geting the data from server. 
                           });
```

Step 4: In your php code make httpwebrequest to get the contents html of that url. And you can use some utility to extract the images and headers out of html you got. Send it as a response to the ajax request you made.

Step 5: you are done. On the success of ajax request you append the data you sent from server to your DOM.

Comment: so how is it possible to get the images and text of the particular url

Comment: so you posted a url to server right? now server will extract the whole document i.e view source. Then you can extract all the imag tags out of it and send back as a ajax response .

Comment: Also you need server intervention since due to cross domain restriction it can not be done only via jQuery or javascript.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @Ashirvad . Mr xlordt have given the excellent answer. You can see http://youhack.me/2011/06/25/create-a-facebook-wall-system-using-php-and-jquery-part-1/